# Expand div full height

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to expand the black box (id: column-content) to the full height without scroll bars.

I try alot of things but nothing works.

Here is the url: http://goo.gl/I5f0u59

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vh` and `vw` (viewport-height and viewport-width)

in your case:

```
#column-content
{
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* 
    change width, since we use border-box
    old width + padding
    */
    width: 480px; 
}
```

As you see, this will make your column content `box-sizing:border-box` this will prevent the container from becoming bigger than `100vh` because of the padding-top and bottom. The content can still lead to an overflow. You will also have to set a new width, like shown above.

The support for this usecase is ok [See here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Not bad. I added some more text in my box. When I scroll I can see the text on the bottom but the black area did not fill this portion of text. Any idea hot to have the black background to keep expanding full height?

Comment: use `min-height: 100vh;` and remove the `height` property. Just by the way, you should have included a minum example in your question...

Answer (score 0):

```
#column-content {
  bottom:0;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```