# Expanding the black background on whole height and be able to scroll if needed

Tags: css

On the following page http://goo.gl/I5f0159 you'll see that the text in the box go outside of the page so when we scroll we can see all the text and the black background is correctly expanding.

On the following page http://goo.gl/P2N52uM you'll see that the text in the box is small but the problem is I would like the black background to expand on full height.

I need a css fix to be apply on both pages so no matter the height of the text, I would like the black background to fill the height.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583180/expand-div-full-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your page and content divs to 100%

```
#page, #content {height: 100%;}
```

Also add `#column-content { overflow: auto; }`

The background stops at the height of the viewport because of `#page {overflow: hidden;}`

Adding a scroll bar to `#column-content` for only when text exceeds the height of the viewport will solve this.

Comment: I updated as you suggest but the black background is not filled correctly for the TH page. Try to visit this page and scroll. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be opposed to a scrollbar on the content area? if not I have an immediate fix

Comment: What are you thinking about?

Comment: Just for curiosity, let me know if my solution works as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules keeping the current CSS properties on both pages:

```
#page{
height: auto;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

Of course you can override and edit this property or at least add the one above after

```
#page, #content {
height: 100%;
}
```